# gdbinit "no such file or directory" Eclipse c

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse-3.5

I'm using Xming to connect to a Linux (enterprise edition) server on which I'm trying to debug a C++ project in Eclipse Galileo. The following errors occurred:

1. Reading symbols from ../workspace/myfile ..(no debugging symbols found) ... done.
   .gdbinit : No such file or directory
   Setting environment variable "LS_COLORS " to null value

(.gdbinit is on the server (in root), my account has rights)

1. If i try to run gmake on the same file from the terminal I get the following error :
   gmake ** No rule to make target /workspace/myfile' . Stop.
   //I have exported the path (including the library path), and gmake exists.

   My project has 3 subprojects (proj1 , proj2 and proj 3). In order to debug proj3 I have to build projs 1 and 2 . I created make targets for projects 1 and 2, and I obtained .so files for which i made softlinks to corresponding files in my_project/libs folder.

My Eclipse debug configuration is as follows (tab order):

Main
  Project: My Project
  Build Configuration: UseActive
  C++ Application: path to my project/myproject
  Environment: path to libs on server (my user rights)
Debugger 
  Debugger: gdb/mi
  (Checked) Stop startup at main
  GDB debugger: gdb
  GDB command line .gdbinit
  GDB command set: standard
  Protocol mi

Project Properties:
  Builders CDT Builder
  Scanner Configuration Builder
  C/C++ Build
  Build command gmake -k
Behaviour 
  build incremental build  : all ( sometimes i get the error no rule for make all)
  Clean: clean
  Discovery options:
    (Checked) Automatic discovery path
    (checked) Report path detection problems
    Discovery profile GCC per project
    (checked ) Enable build output
    Compile invocation comand gcc
    Toolchain
    No toolchain
    Correct builder GNU make builder

This Eclipse debug configuration works on another account (on the same server using the same Eclipse). The gdbinit and gmake files are on the server and work, I'm not supposed to update the versions (this was one solution I found online).

Has anyone seen this error before? Does anyone have a clue what I'm doing wrong?